# Multiple SMTP servers in Thunderbird3

Tags: thunderbird

Situation:

2 mail accounts - each with its own pop3 and smtp servers, accesed normally.

Except, when using Vodafone mobile network (you know, those usb or pcmcia cards ...) in which case mails are send using Vodafone's SMTP server.

I configured both accounts in thunderbird for their default servers, and then added under multiple identities, another called Name of User (mobile) for each account. And it works.
Except, I don't like the fact that when I send mail using mobile smtp server it sends them under Name of User *(mobile)* <-- the mobile part being important.

I could of course, delete that part, but then when sending mail, I'd have no way of differenting between the two. They'd both look as Name of User email@address_of_user.com.

So, what would be the easiest way to solve this ? *It is not a major problem, but it is annoying.*

Comment: What do you wanna solve? You don't wanna remove it because you use it for tracking, but you don't wanna have it either...just use something in the name only you will see, like a additional, reorder the name or something.

Comment: @Bobby - Yes. I want to have on both only "Name", not "Name (mobile)" - since that is something my clients will see. But I cannot find any other way to differentiate between the two, without changing the account name.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the identities by their order, so if you are going to name both Identities the same **User**, then you just have to check once which identity is which and remember it.

As the commenter Bobby had pointed out, there's not a lot more you can do about it, apart from slightly altering the user name so that clients won't notice but you can identify the account.